# How do I traverse elements of 2d list efficiently and change them to what I want?

Tags: python, arrays, list

`inStock` - 2D list (row size:10, column size:4)

`delta` = [3, 5, 2, 6, 10, 9, 7, 11, 1, 8]

g. Write the definition of the function `setInStock` that prompts the user to input the elements for the first column of `inStock`.  The function should then set the elements in the remaining columns to two times the corresponding element in the previous column, minus the corresponding element in `delta`.

Please help me with this function.

Comment: Unfortunately this post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.

Comment: Please also show what you have done and where you are stuck. Review the material describing [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This also sounds a bit like an assignment, so if applicable [this link discussing homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) could also be useful.

Comment: When preparing code for help consider using a tuple for instock processing, item(row, column).